# How to parse kafka message in KafkaSpout and set in tuple value

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to read kafka messages from KafkaSpout and set tuple values from json that are parsed from that message. Actually, I am creating an additional Bolt that parses a tuple field called "value" with json string from KafkaSpout. Is it possible to set these values in Spout?

```
class ScanConfigKafkaSpout(kafkaUrl: String, kafkaGroup: String, kafkaTopic: String) : KafkaSpout<String, String>(
    KafkaSpoutConfig
        .builder(kafkaUrl, kafkaTopic)
        .setProp(KEY_KAFKA_GROUP, "grp1")
        .setProcessingGuarantee(KafkaSpoutConfig.ProcessingGuarantee.AT_MOST_ONCE)
        .build()
), ComponentId {
    override fun open(conf: MutableMap<String, Any>?, context: TopologyContext?, collector: SpoutOutputCollector?) {
        try {
            logger.debug("<${id()}> Opening ScanConfigKafkaSpout  with ${conf.toString()}")
            super.open(conf, context, collector)
            logger.debug("<${id()}> ScanConfigKafkaSpout opened")
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            logger.error("<${id()}> Error during opening CrawlScanConfigKafkaSpout", t)
        }
    }

    override fun id(): String = SCAN_CONFIG_KAFKA_SPOUT

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScanConfigKafkaSpout::class.java)
    }

}
```

Comment: Where and how do you add this bolt in the topology? Can you show that code too?

Comment: @moosehead42 some like that:  ```topologyBuilder.addSpout(scanConfigKafkaSpout).addBolt(bolt = scanConfigUpdaterBolt, shuffleGrouping = scanConfigKafkaSpout)```

Comment: I would be happy, if you accept my answer. :-)

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's not solution of my problem. I need parse JSON from kafka message in KafkaSpout and directly inject into tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to implement the method `declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer` from `IComponent`.

It is used by Storm to serialize your attribute values and tuple configurations.

As stated [here](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Tutorial.html) in the section *Data Model* , it says:

> **Every node in a topology must declare the output fields for the tuples it emits.**

There is also a java example given for that method.

```java
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
  declarer.declare(new Fields("double", "triple"));
}
```